# Error when opening .sh files (void-function sh-set-offset)

Tags: configuration-files

I've updated and now I get this error when opening a new .sh file, or any .sh file for that matter.

Any pointers as to what I can try?

Any smart bisect method to use when I have a literate emacs file?;)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function sh-set-offset)
  (sh-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
  (lambda nil (sh-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook sh-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook sh-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(sh-mode-hook)
  sh-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(sh-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode--apply-alist((("\\.\\(?:md\\|markdown\\|mkd\\|mdown\\|mkdn\\|mdwn\\)\\'" . markdown-mode) ("\\.pdf$" . gpdf-mode) ("\\.jpg$" . gimp-mode) ("\\.txt\\'" . org-mode) ("\\.ledger$" . ledger-mode) ("\\.ses$" . ses-mode) ("\\.org$" . org-mode) ("\\.gpg$" . sensitive-mode) ("\\.tsx\\'" . typescript-mode) ("\\.ts\\'" . typescript-mode) ("\\.cs\\'" . csharp-mode) ("\\.xml?\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.scss?\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.css\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.[agj]sp\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode) ("\\.js\\'" . javascript-mode) ("\\.java$" . java-mode) ("\\.gpg\\(~\\|\\.~[0-9]+~\\)?\\'" nil epa-file) ("\\.elc\\'" . elisp-byte-code-mode) ("\\.zst\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.dz\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.xz\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.lzma\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.lz\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.g?z\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.bz2\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.Z\\'" nil jka-compr) ("\\.vr[hi]?\\'" . vera-mode) ("\\(?:\\.\\(?:rbw?\\|ru\\|rake\\|thor\\|jbuilder\\|rabl\\|ge..." . ruby-mode) ("\\.re?st\\'" . rst-mode) ("\\.py[iw]?\\'" . python-mode) ("\\.m\\'" . octave-maybe-mode) ("\\.less\\'" . less-css-mode) ("\\.scss\\'" . scss-mode) ("\\.awk\\'" . awk-mode) ("\\.\\(u?lpc\\|pike\\|pmod\\(\\.in\\)?\\)\\'" . pike-mode) ("\\.idl\\'" . idl-mode) ("\\.java\\'" . java-mode) ("\\.m\\'" . objc-mode) ("\\.ii\\'" . c++-mode) ("\\.i\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.lex\\'" . c-mode) ("\\.y\\(acc\\)?\\'" . c-mode) ...) nil nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(t t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer foo.sh> "~/foo.sh" nil nil "~/foo.sh" nil)
  find-file-noselect("/home/b0ef/foo.sh" nil nil nil)
  find-file("/home/b0ef/foo.sh")
  counsel-find-file-action("/home/b0ef/foo.sh")
  ivy-call()
  ivy-read("Find file: " read-file-name-internal :matcher counsel--find-file-matcher :initial-input nil :action counsel-find-file-action :preselect nil :require-match confirm-after-completion :history file-name-history :keymap (keymap (remap keymap (undo . counsel-find-file-undo)) (67108960 lambda (&optional arg) "nil (`nil')" (interactive "p") (if (string= "" ivy-text) (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "M-o b")) (self-insert-command arg))) (96 . counsel-file-jump-from-find) (C-backspace . counsel-up-directory) (67108991 . counsel-up-directory)) :caller counsel-find-file)
  counsel--find-file-1("Find file: " nil counsel-find-file-action counsel-find-file)
  counsel-find-file()
  funcall-interactively(counsel-find-file)
  call-interactively(counsel-find-file nil nil)
  command-execute(counsel-find-file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the contents of `sh-mode-hook` with `C-h v sh-mode-hook`: looks like you, or a package you have loaded, has something in there that calls the non-existing function `sh-set-offset`.

Comment: Thanks. I had this code: (add-hook 'sh-mode-hook (lambda () (sh-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))) Don't know what it is and from where I got it;)